# Selenium Dynamic xpath handling

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have one Checkbox with `input type="checkbox" value="1053" name="filelist"`

If the user uploads more files for each file one Check box will add in the webpage.
    But the value was changing for that
       `input type="checkbox" value="424" name="filelist"`

Please help me how to check a specific CheckBox,when  the Value is Changing for each one and others are same.

Answer (score 0):

Use findelements method to read all check boxes using name or relative xpath.

findelements return list.you can use any check box.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if you do not get any unique attribute to locate an element then in that case you can use xpath always. But again as your question explains there is noting unique constant attribute value by which you can create a relative xpath. So my suggestion is: either use a relative xpath which will start from uploaded file details like this:

```
 //file[@id='foo']/input[@type='checkbox']
```

or  find all the checkbox elements by using `findElements` and do whatever you want to do by iterating a loop for list of web-elements. It will look like something:

```
Lis<WebElement> allChkBoxes = driver.findElements(By.name('filelist'));
// to click on first one
allChkBoxes.get(1).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all elements by any methods like By.cssSelector() or By.name() and click them with the help of loop:

```
List<WebElement> allCheckBoxes=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']"));
for(WebElement checkBox:allCheckBoxes){
      checkBox.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no unique property available in your case, you can use Indexes:

```
String xPath = //input[@type='checkbox'][name='filelist'][i]
```

where i = index i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc. And then,

```
WebElement chkBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
chkBox.click();
```